# Pasar un array desde php por get

Tags: php

Tengo en php este array.

```
$error = array();
$error["error"] ="Tamaño máximo superado"
```

Antes de mandarlo realizo esto

```
$error = serialize($error);
$error = urldecode($error);
header("Location: subidaarchivos.php?".$error);
```

Pero al llegar a la otra página me llega así en la ruta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma correcta de hacer lo que deseas es:

```
<?php
/* En la captura de tu pregunta aparenta estar definido así 'error' */
$error = [ 'error' => '<li>Tamaño máximo superado</li>' ];
$error = serialize($error);
$error = urlencode($error);
/* OJO: agregamos 'mensaje=' para que en el otro lado llegue como $_GET['mensaje'] */
header("Location: subidaarchivos.php?mensaje=" . $error);
```

Tras convertir la matriz `$error` en una cadena debemos codificarla en URL con [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) para poder agregarlo a la URL posteriormente, pero **en tu ejemplo lo estás decodificando con [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode)**.

Y en el extremo receptor el trabajo es más sencillo:

```
<?php
/* Comprobamos que ha llegado correctamente el campo 'error' */
if (isset($_GET['mensaje'])) {
    /* Deshacemos el trabajo hecho por 'serialize' */
    $error = unserialize($_GET['mensaje']);
    // El contenido del error está en el índice 'error'
    die($error['error']);
}
```

Los datos llegan correctamente bien formados al contenido de la variable `$_GET['mensaje']`, sólo te queda deshacer el trabajo de `serialize` para acceder de nuevo a los datos con [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize).

Por último, como es una matriz, deberás acceder al índice `error` para poder mostrar el contenido del error.

URL generada:

```
subidaarchivos.php?mensaje=a%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A5%3A%22error%22%3Bs%3A33%3A%22%3Cli%3ETama%C3%B1o+m%C3%A1ximo+superado%3C%2Fli%3E%22%3B%7D
```

---

**Solución alternativa ocultando datos en URL**

Se pueden ocultar fácilmente los datos que aparecen en la URL usando, por ejemplo, [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/base64_encode).

```
<?php
/* En la captura de tu pregunta aparenta estar definido así 'error' */
$error = [ 'error' => '<li>Tamaño máximo superado</li>' ];
$error = serialize($error);
$error = base64_encode($error);
$error = urlencode($error);
/* OJO: agregamos 'error=' para que en el otro lado llegue como $_GET['mensaje'] */
header("Location: subidaarchivos.php?mensaje=" . $error);
```

Y en el lado de recepción:

```
<?php
/* Comprobamos que ha llegado correctamente el campo 'error' */
if (isset($_GET['mensaje'])) {
    /* Deshacemos el trabajo hecho por base64_encode */
    $error = base64_decode($_GET['mensaje']);
    /* Deshacemos el trabajo hecho por 'serialize' */
    $error = unserialize($error);
    // El contenido del error está en el índice 'error'
    die($error['error']);
}
```

Básicamente introducimos un paso adicional que codifica y decodifica en base64 los datos que aparecerán en la URL, ocultando a simple vista su contenido o significado:

URL generada:

```
subidaarchivos.php?mensaje=YToxOntzOjU6ImVycm9yIjtzOjMzOiI8bGk%2BVGFtYcOxbyBtw6F4aW1vIHN1cGVyYWRvPC9saT4iO30%3D
```

Answer (score 3):

Al enviar

```
<?php
  $arrayError= Array(["error"]=>"Tamaño máximo superado");

  $urlPortion= '&error='.urlencode(serialize($arrayError));

  header("Location: subidaarchivos.php?".$urlPortion);?
?>
```

Al recibir

```
<?php
    $receptor=unserialize($_GET['error']);
?>
```

Comment: El `&` de `'&error='` no es necesario y donde pones `Array(["error"]=>"Tamaño máximo superado")` deberías poner `Array("error"=>"Tamaño máximo superado")` o, mejor aún, `[ "error" => "Tamaño máximo superado" ]`.

Answer (score 2):

Al recibirlo deberías hacer esto, dado que no puedes serializar el array y luego no desserializarlo

```
<?php
 $error = unserialize($_GET["error"]); 
?>
```

Comment: Este código lanza una advertencia avisando que el índice `error` de `$_GET` no está definido y, por ende, no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Enviar datos y recibirlo en el mismo archivo por GET, a mi me funció este código:

```html
<?php
//LEER DATOS
if (isset($_GET['referencia'])) 
{
  /* Deshacemos 'serialize' */
  $referencia = unserialize($_GET['referencia']);
  echo "Datos 1: ",$referencia[1]."<br>";
  echo "Datos 2: ",$referencia[2]."<br>";
  echo "Datos 3: ",$referencia[3]."<br>";
  echo "Datos 4: ",$referencia[4]."<br>";
}
?>


<?php
//AGREGA DATOS AL ARREGLO
$referencia[1] = $check_1;
$referencia[2] = $check_2;
$referencia[3] = $check_3;
$referencia[4] = $check_4;
?>

<!-- ENVIAMOS DATOS POR GET en un FORM -->
<form action="archivo.php?referencia=<?php echo urlencode(serialize($referencia)); ?>" method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
<form>
```